# Positioning Magento blocks disjointed like a puzzle

Tags: magento

I have a vision for my web shop whereby I can position static blocks of different sizes in any way I prefer, like a puzzle.

Below is an image showing the main idea:
[image]

Ideally I'd be able to create all sorts of patterns.

[image]

Is this in any way possible with the current Magento setup by creating a custom template with a grid in which I can organize the blocks disjointed?

Comment: For the most part, yes you can. You'd have to start from a clean layout + template with no parent template but yes it's flexible enough to support that.

Comment: web is not a puzzle. To just create a html + css for the first example isn't a trivial task (taking into account vertical positioned block). I can't think of any rules which would allow you to manipulate page layout like that.

Comment: As Mihai said, Magento template is flexible enough to allow you have any layout you want. The solution you are looking is not Magento specific. So you have to figure algorithm that allow arranging html blocks.

Comment: Is this something you've seen on another site? Perhaps the [isotope.js](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/beta/) plugin might achieve what you're looking for? If you're not looking for something dynamic, HTML + CSS is the way to go. It will take some work but shouldn't be very difficult.

Comment: Yeh use isotope - it is good solution. But if you have more than ~100 block then you need a little optimize isotope. ))

Comment: http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: It isn't as simple as you think, Yes, Magento can be modified like this, but you must decide where will be basic shopping tools like cart, header menu etc... Some layouts depending on other layouts, that means, you cant not load some before another. So it is possible, but not exactly like isotope solution.

Comment: This question isn't really Magento specific, all you need is a few main CMS pages with css for the different grid layouts. Those will in turn include CMS blocks that will be positioned by the CMS pages design. So yeah, it's just pure CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. The question I see you will find the most challenge from is how would you sort the blocks in the back end? are you going to add a position field to the object static block?

One way really easy that you can achieve that is by giving all of these blocks simple and preassigned keys, for example: pizza-01, pizza-02, pizza-03, etc. Then you can develop in your theme file a small logic that will loop 01-99 and pull all the blocks that exist & are enabled & have non-empty output in their proper order. The rest is then left to the CSS, so you can display it in a grid like way or mosaic or whatever.